# Saturation of pure binomial homogeneous ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $2q$ monomials $m_1, m'_1, \cdots, m_q, m'_q$ of the polynomial ring ${\mathbb Z}[X_1, \cdots, X_n]$ such $\deg(m_i) = \deg(m'_i) := d_i$. I note $I$ the binomial ideal $I = \langle m_1 - m'_1, \cdots, m_q - m'_q\rangle$ and $J$ it's saturation.

My question is : have we the equality of homogeneous components:
$$
I_d = J_d  \quad \forall d \ge (d_1-1) + \cdots + (d_q-1)
$$
Thanks for your answer.